# MobileFirst 7.0 Studio - Android 2.3.x support

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0

I see in the MobileFirst System requirement that it supports from
Android 2.3.3 base version:

http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/osForProduct?deliverableId=4DB072503A2F11E396F9FC10E99BE807#MobileOS_(4)

Created a HelloWorld project, added an app and the android environment, and run it on Android device with Android OS 2.3.3.

The application freeze on splash screen. The same is working fine in android 4.0 or later. Not able to trace the error log in Studio.

I have customers they are still using android 2.3.3 devices. :(

[CatLog](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yf60fyjg7mk18l4/CatLog.txt?dl=0)

Comment: 2.3.x is not defined enough. Which specific 2.3.x (what is 'x') and which specific devices.

Comment: And add the full logcat. If you can, also provide your project because I don't know what is your definition for "simple".

Comment: Hi Adar, i update the question with the log.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be able to test only on Monday.

Comment: Thanks Adar, Happy weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0.0.00-20150430-1556 with the Form-based authentication sample and the app worked for me... on HTC with Android 2.3.5... so cannot confirm that it does not work.

Comment: Hi Idan, My MFPF Server and Studio version is 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731. Might be this version may have some issue. I will try to apply the latest fix pack on my eclipse studio and post you.